# searching a file and inserting a value in the database

Tags: python, database

i am writing this script to open a file and search for a string in it , in this case "Games" and once it is encountered open the db connection and insert a value of "1" in to a column called "feature " , the code works fine but it doesn't insert the value 1 in to that particular column .

```
#!/usr/bin/python
flag1=0
flag2=0
flag3=0
#open a file 
file = open("foo.txt", mode="r")
print 'Brian'
for line in file:
    if "Games" in line and flag1==0:
        print 'found "Games " in file'
        flag1=1            
                # Open database connection
        import MySQLdb
        db = MySQLdb.connect("apps_dev@test.net","apps_dev","TeStUsEr","apps_dev" )
           print 'insert value 1 '
                # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
        cursor = db.cursor() # to traversal the records in a DB
                # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
        sql = """INSERT INTO (Feature) VALUE (1)"""

        try:
                # Execute the SQL command
            cursor.execute(sql)
                # Commit your changes in the database
            db.commit()
        except:
                # Rollback in case there is any error
            db.rollback()
                # disconnect from server
    db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your query stmt,
It should be:

```
Insert into TheTableName(Feature) values (1)
```

in your case you are not defining a table to put 1 into

Comment: @Brian, can you make this change in your code and try again?

Comment: @jay hi jay i tried and it's not working , i dont know what is the issue

Comment: it doesn't give me any error , it just prints "brian" and found games in file , that means it's reading the file and searching for this string but it doesn't do the main stuff i.e writing the value "1" in the feature column , well i run this code through CLI on a server .

Comment: I don't see any error check to see if you connected to the db in the first place. Check to see if you have successfully connected to the db

Comment: i wrote a print statement to see if the cursor is even going to db statement .